# Rewrite rule match ALL not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I want any visitor to a site: https://domain.example.com/[IP Address] to actually get the contents of: https://domain.example.com/api-index?ip=[IP Address].

I thought this one is easy:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api-index.php?ip=$1 [L]
```

It is actually loading content from api-index.php, but not the ?ip=$1 part.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165910/htaccess-rewrite-rule-ends-in-an-infinite-loop).

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* api-index.php?ip=$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it should work fine. You can *test* it by temporarily adding R=302 to your `RewriteRule` flags as then you will see the new address in your browser.

If I may suggest, you *may* find it easier to use `FallBackResrouce /api-index.php` and parse the PATHINFO

Comment: Actually, I tested R=302 and it generates an infinite redirect loop. When using RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api-index.php?ip=$1 [L] I tested printing the $_GET and what i get is Array ( [ip] => api-index.php ), not the [IP ADDRESS] which is what i would be expecting since I'm asking for https://api.domain.com/[IP ADRRESS]